# Count associations based on attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Given a class, I would like to return all objects (`index`) sorted by the number of associations they have with a specific attribute.

For example, let's say `User has_many :fish` I want to show a list of all users and order them by how many  `:fish` they have that are `color: :red` (Assuming that's an enum/integer value)

Users with 0 red fish, or 0 fish at all, should still be shown on the table, but sorted to the bottom.

```
-- User -- | - # of fish - | - # of red fish -
    2      |      10       |        10
    5      |      25       |         7
    6      |      11       |         6
    7      |      18       |         5
    1      |      27       |         4
    3      |      23       |         1
    4      |       3       |         0
    8      |       0       |         0
```

So far I've managed to sort the User by the number of fish they have using the `left_join` gem, but I'm having trouble sorting by an attribute on that model.

This is how I am sorting by the number of fish:

`@users = User.left_join(:fish).group("user.id").order("count(user.id) desc")`

Any help would be awesome! I'm assuming this is trivial, but I'm also displaying that data as well, so any way to store that data temporarily would be awesome too! (I'm assuming using a `select` and setting the counts as variables)

EDIT:

**Solution**, thanks to Anthony E.

```
@users = User.select("users.*")
             .joins("LEFT JOIN fishes ON fishes.user_id = users.id")
             .where(fishes: { color: Fish.colors[:red] } )
             .group("users.id").order("COUNT(fishes.id) DESC")
             .page(params[:page]) // To work with Kaminari/pagination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
User.select("user.*, COUNT(fish.id) AS fish_count")
      .joins(:fish)
      .where(fish: { color: "red" })
      .group("user.id")
      .order("fish_count DESC")
```

The benefit is that you can call `fish_count` on each object in the returned returned collection because it's in your `select`

**EDIT**

To include users with 0 fish, use a LEFT JOIN and modify the where clause:

```
User.select("user.*, COUNT(fish.id) AS fish_count")
      .joins("LEFT JOIN ON fish.user_id = user.id")
      .where("fish.color = 'red' OR fish.color IS NULL")
      .group("user.id")
      .order("fish_count DESC")
```

Comment: This raises a `PG::UndefinedTable` error in the case where a user has 0 fish. (I believe this happens because of the `count` in the `select`)

Comment: That's odd, users with no fish should be excluded via the `joins` clause. Your table names are `user` and `fish`, correct? If you add `.where.not(fish: { user_id: nil })` after the `joins(:fish)` function, does the issue persist?

Comment: Excluding them would be a problem regardless- it's still supposed to show all Users regardless of their fish count, simply sorted by their fish count. (Which is why I was using `left_join` instead of just `joins`) - although you're correct. I'm not sure why that is raising an issue.

Comment: I'm confused by this statement: `@user = @user.left_join(:fish).group("user.id").order("count(user.id) desc")`. Is @user a collection or an instance of a model? Did you intend to write `User.joins(:fish).group("user.id").order("count(user.id) desc")`?

Comment: Sorry- that was a typo. Supposed to be `@users = User.blah.blah`

Comment: To answer your question- yes, the problem persists while including `.where.not(fish: { user_id: nil })`

Comment: OK, the problem then is that the `where(fish: { color: 'red' })` implies that the user as one or more fishes. I've edited my answer to account for a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: After changing it to `.joins("LEFT JOIN fishes ON fishes.user_id = user.id")` (It wasn't joining on a column) it fell back to the `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user"` error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109472/discussion-between-anthony-e-and-rockster160).